# Prove or disprove: $\dim(\text{range}(S^{-1}TS)) = \dim(\text{range}(T))$ and even $\operatorname{range}(S^{-1}TS) = \operatorname{range}(T)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Prove or disprove: $\dim \left( \operatorname{range} \left( S^{-1} T S \right) \right) = \dim \left( \operatorname{range} \left( T \right) \right)$, where $S$ is invertible and $T, S \in L(V)$.

I intuitively think it is true, because $S$ is invertible and it doesn't change the column space and row space of $M(T)$, where $M(T)$ is the matrix of $T$. But I cannot give a strict proof.

Or if I can prove $\dim \left( \operatorname{null} \left( S^{-1} T S \right) \right) = \dim \left( \operatorname{null} \left( T \right) \right)$, I can say $\dim \left( \operatorname{range} \left( S^{-1} T S \right) \right) = \dim \left( \operatorname{range} \left( T \right) \right)$ because of Fundamental theorem of linear algebra. But I failed.

And what's more I wonder whether $\operatorname{range} \left( S^{-1} T S \right) = \operatorname{range} \left( T \right)$ or not.

Comment: If one of the answers below worked for you personally, please accept it by clicking on the check-mark on the left of the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First, we must prove that $\operatorname{range}\left(S^{-1}TS\right)=\operatorname{range}\left(S^{-1}T\right).$

*Proof*. Let $x\in\operatorname{range}\left(S^{-1}TS\right)$ be arbitrary, then $x=S^{-1}TS(v)$ for some $v\in V$. Since $x=S^{-1}TS(v)=S^{-1}T(S(v))$ for some $S(v)\in V$, then $x\in\operatorname{range}\left(S^{-1}T\right)$. Therefore, $\operatorname{range}\left(S^{-1}TS\right)\subseteq\operatorname{range}\left(S^{-1}T\right).$

Let $x\in\operatorname{range}\left(S^{-1}T\right)$ be arbitrary, then $x=S^{-1}T(v)$ for some $v\in V$. Since $x=S^{-1}T(v)=S^{-1}T(SS^{-1}(v))=S^{-1}TS(S^{-1}(v))$ for some $S^{-1}(v)\in V$, then $x\in\operatorname{range}\left(S^{-1}TS\right)$. Therefore, $\operatorname{range}\left(S^{-1}T\right)\subseteq\operatorname{range}\left(S^{-1}TS\right).$

Therefore, $\operatorname{range}\left(S^{-1}TS\right)=\operatorname{range}\left(S^{-1}T\right).$ In particular,
$$\tag{*} \label{*} \dim\operatorname{range}\left(S^{-1}TS\right)=\dim\operatorname{range}\left(S^{-1}T\right).$$

- Second, we must prove that $\operatorname{range}\left(S^{-1}T\right)\simeq\operatorname{range}\left(T\right).$

*Proof.* Let $\varphi:\operatorname{range}\left(T\right)\to\operatorname{range}\left(S^{-1}T\right)$ be a linear transformation defined by $\varphi(x)=S^{-1}x$.

Let $x,y\in\operatorname{range}\left(T\right)$. Note that
$$\varphi(x)=\varphi(y)\implies S^{-1}x=S^{-1}y\implies SS^{-1}x=SS^{-1}y\implies x=y.$$
Therefore, $\varphi$ is injective.

Now, let $y\in\operatorname{range}\left(S^{-1}T\right)$ be arbitrary. Choose $x=Sy$. Thus, $x\in\operatorname{range}\left(T\right)$ and
$$\varphi(x)=\varphi(Sy)=S^{-1}\left(Sy\right)=y.$$
Therefore, $\varphi$ is surjective.

Therefore, $\operatorname{range}\left(S^{-1}T\right)\simeq\operatorname{range}\left(T\right).$ It follows that
$$\tag{**} \label{**}\dim\operatorname{range}\left(S^{-1}T\right)=\dim\operatorname{range}\left(T\right).$$

- Finally, it follows from $(\ref{*})$ and $(\ref{**})$ that
  $$\boxed{\dim\operatorname{range}\left(S^{-1}TS\right)=\dim\operatorname{range}\left(T\right)}.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint: I suggest you to see the set of matrix $S$ and $S^{-1}$ as an expression for basis changing, under the conception of linear transformation.**
I will prove the dimension first using a trick like the sandwich rule in the calculus.
For any vector $\vec{v_1}$ in the nullspace of $S^{-1}TS$, we have $S^{-1}TS\vec{v_1}=0$.
We know the matrix $S^{-1}$ is invertible so we have $TS\vec{v_1}=0$, so we find the vector $S\vec{v_1}\in Null(T)$.
If we set $\vec y=S\vec{v_1}$, so for every vector $\vec{v_1}$ in the null space of $S^{-1}TS\vec{v_1}$, there will always be a corresponding vector $\vec y=S\vec{v_1}$ in the nullspace of matrix $S$. 
And for different $\vec{v_1}$, there will be different $\vec y$. That means $dim(Null(S^{-1}TS))\leq dim(Null(T))$  
Now we can work with the other side.
If we find a vector $\vec{u_1}$ that in the nullspace of matrix $T$. Then we will know $T\vec{u_1}=0$.
Now we can find a corresponding vector $\vec{z}$ that satisfies $S\vec{z}=\vec{u_1}$, then we will have $S^{-1}TS\vec{z}=S^{-1}T\vec{u_1}=0$, 
then we will know that $\vec{z}$ is in the nullspace of the matrix $S^{-1}TS$.
We know that the matix T is invertible, sofor every different $\vec{u_1}$, there will always be a different solution for corresponding $\vec{z}$, that means $dim(Null(S^{-1}TS))\geq dim(Null(T))$.
To conclude there is only one way to satisfy both the unequality (1) and (2) which is $dim(Null(S^{-1}TS))= dim(Null(T))$.
We know the row space is the orthogonal complement of the nullspace, so we have $dim(Row(S^{-1}TS))= dim(Row(T))$ .
We also know that for a matrix, after the Gaussian Elimination, the dimension of the column space and the dimension of the rowspace are both the number of the pivots.
So we got $dim(Column(S^{-1}TS))= dim(Column(T))$, which is just $dim(range(S^{-1}TS))= dim(range(T))$ 
Now I want to prove the second one is wrong.
I plan to disprove it by a counterexample and explain it by the idea of basis changing in the linear transformation.
if you choose $T$ to be $\left[\begin{matrix}0&0\\0&1\end{matrix}\right]$, and choose $S$ to be $\left[\begin{matrix}0&1\\1&0\end{matrix}\right]$, then we will have $S^{-1}TS$ to be $\left[\begin{matrix}1&0\\0&0\end{matrix}\right]$. You can find with your eyesight that $range(T)\neq range(S^{-1}TS)$.
But I am more willing to expain it in the language of basis changing in the linear transformation.
**A deeper sight by basis changing**
We know if we see the matrix in the way of linear transformation, then we can see the pair of inveritble matrix a s a pair of transition matrix, so it will not change the exact value of the linear transformation, however it will change teh basis to describe it. And we know that for the same vector, we will get the expression on the different basis to be different. That is why the range of the matrix before and after the basis changing is different.

Answer (score 0):

Since $S$ is invertible, $range(T) = range(TS)$ (you can precompose by $S^{-1}$). Furthermore, since $S^{-1}$ is invertible, $range(TS)$ and $range(S^{-1}TS)$ are isomorphic. In particular, they have the same dimension.